# Multiplying factors of a positive number

Tags: elementary-number-theory, factoring

The task is to find a singel positive whole number(X), where all the factors of that number(X) multiplied together equal $24^{240}$

Comment: Sorry but the question is not clear to me. The product of the factors of a number  alwayf give that number. What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried writing $24^{240}$ as a product of prime factors?

Comment: From my reading of the question you seem to be looking for a single positive integer where if you list all its factors and multiply them together the answer makes $24^{240}$ ... am I right?

Comment: Hi. We encourage the posters to show us their attempts so we can help them identify the difficulties. Please edit your question, otherwise the question would be put on hold or closed.

Comment: Exactly, I have to find a singel positive number(X), where all the factors of that number(X) multiplied together equal 24^240

Answer (score 2):

First we write $24^{240}$ as the product of its prime factors:
$$24^{240}=2^{720}3^{240}$$
Then note that for any positive integer $n=\prod_{1=1}^m p_i^{\alpha_i}$, where each $p_i$ denotes a distinct prime number, the product of all its factors are
$$\prod_{i_1=0}^{\alpha_1}\prod_{i_2=0}^{\alpha_2}\cdots\prod_{i_m=0}^{\alpha_m}p_1^{i_1}p_2^{i_2}\ldots p_m^{i_m}$$

From this information we can infer that such number $n$ has the form $2^a3^b$ for some positive integer $a,b$. Then multiplying all factors together, we have
$$\prod_{i=0}^{a}\prod_{j=0}^{b}2^i3^j=2^{(b+1)(1+2+\ldots+a)}3^{(a+1)(1+2+\ldots+b)}=2^{720}3^{240}$$
(exercise: show that the expressions on the left and middle of the equation are equal)

Now we have two equations and two unknowns in the exponents of $2$ and $3$. Can you finish the rest?

Comment: +1 Nice solution :)